# Прогнозирование возможных срабатываний системы (детектирование аномалий)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, классификация, временные-ряды, регрессия

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть при решении следующей задачи.
Имеется физическая система, на ложное срабатывание которой теоретически могут влиять физические переключения смежных устройств. В составе есть устройства принимающие дискретные положения (0/1) и аналоговые, меняющиеся в широком диапазоне.

На данный момент пробую применять методы бинарной классификации.
С дискретными параметрами понятно как можно взаимодействовать - достаточно рассматривать временные лаги от момента времени активации системы и фактически фиксировать их переключения в рассматриваемом лаге.

Проблемы заключаются с аналоговыми параметрами - какие метрики можно использовать при подаче их на вход классификатора (на данный момент попробовал использовать СКО в рассматриваемых временных лагах)?

Схематично задача изображена на рисунке ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Честно говоря, вопрос непонятен. Можно брать аналоговые значения с разной задержкой, например. Или там "скользящее среднее" их какое-нибудь за какие-то периоды. Надо смотреть конкретные данные, так абстрактно сложно.

Comment: К сожалению не могу сообщить детали более конкретно. Попробую на аналогичном примере. Допустим, на вход классификатора я могу могу подавать показатели - количество переключений разнотипных дискретных устройств - в такой реализации более-менее все получается прогнозировать. Но не могу на вход того же классификатора подать аналоговое значение - так как этот параметр может меняться в широком диапазоне. Возможно есть варианты подать на вход классификатора предварительно разделенные по типу изменений аналогового параметра (то есть предварительно классифицировав вид изменеия)

Comment: Проблема подхода с подачей класса изменяемого аналогового сигнала состоит в том что, методы классификации достаточно плохо работают с категориальными данными

Comment: Не совсем понятно какое отношение имеют аналоговые значения, изменяющиеся в широком диапазоне к категориальным данным?? Аналоговые параметры имеют дискретные значения?

Comment: Это относится к попытке по преобразованию аналоговых данных к категориальным, для того чтобы скормить их классификаторов.

Comment: @MSA Ну, в принципе, бинаризация аналоговых признаков это один из вариантов. Да много что можно сделать. Классификатор же не требует на входе дискретных значений, все классификаторы, начиная с логистической регрессии, прекрасно работают с аналоговыми данными.

Comment: @CrazyElf проблема заключается в том что я не исследую только один аналоговый параметр, а множество. При этом смотрю не на само значение аналогового параметра, а на выход системы.  Аналоговые параметры при этом может резко поменяться -100 до 100 и не один раз.

Comment: @MSA Для начала объясните, что такое СКО, может я что-то пойму. Пока я всё ещё не понимаю, в чём проблема

Comment: @CrazyElf  "что такое СКО" -  подозреваю, что "средне квадратичное отклонение".

Answer (score 1):

Читаю, но никак не могу врубиться. Классификация - по определению - это когда у вас на выходе номинальные либо ранговые данные, а вот на входе - не важно что. Любой  метод классификации (ну те, что вот слету  вспомнились) прекрасно работают в таком случае -  случае смешанных параметров. Вы на картинке показали случайный лес. Он вообще-то говоря строиться на основе деревьев. А им - все равно какой параметр стоит в узле. Если номинальный, то условие только "совпали или нет", если ранговый -  то добавляется "больше-меньше", если интервальный, отношений или абсолютный - то вы можете формулировать условия в виде "больше Х", "меньше Х", и как раз алгоритм построения деревьев эти самые Х может определить.

Не очень понял ваше описание, но если вас интересуют не сами значения входных параметров, а факт их изменения, то во первых, вы должны сказать, что вы понимаете под изменением (например, изменение от значения 67 до значения 67.5 -  это изменение или нет?), и тогда вы от непосредственных значений своего измеряемого параметра переходите к анализу события перехода. Кстати, для обнаружения факта "Изменения значения параметра" (разладки, выброса, аномалии и пр) применяется своя группа методов, в том числе и на основе СКО, хотя есть и более тонкие методы.

То, что задача решаемая - ну представьте, у вас объект - это пациент, параметры его описания могут быть какими угодно, а диагнозы методами машинного обучения последние годы ставятся все более точные. Типичная задача классификации, еще и многозначной, а не бинарной. Чем это принципиально отличается от вашей задачи? Объектом, но не возможными методами ее решения.

Comment: Вот и я ничего не понял. И не смог добиться от автора вопроса )